# Vertical scrollbar in FF and Chrome (sticky footer)

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have this [code](http://codepen.io/cove3010/pen/PZMLQm):

```css
/**
 * CSSReset.com - How To Keep Footer At Bottom of Page with CSS
 * 
 * Original Tutorial: http://www.cssreset.com/2010/css-tutorials/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/
 * License: Free - do whatever you like with it! Credit and linkbacks much appreciated.
 *
 * NB: Make sure the value for 'padding-bottom' on #content is equal to or greater than the height of #footer.
 */
html,
body {
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
 min-height:100%;
 position:relative;
}
#header {
 background:#ededed;
 padding:10px;
}
#content {
 padding-bottom:100px; /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
 background:#ffab62;
 width:100%;
 height:100px;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <style type="text/css">
   #wrapper { height:100%; }
  </style>
 <![endif]-->
<body>

 <div id="wrapper">
  
  <div id="header">
  </div><!-- #header -->
  
  <div id="content">
  </div><!-- #content -->
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel tellus eros. Cras id sapien vulputate, molestie mauris convallis, vestibulum mi. Nullam vestibulum interdum massa, quis feugiat dolor venenatis id. Nulla pellentesque pharetra consectetur. Curabitur placerat neque sed ex mattis lobortis. Quisque vitae hendrerit urna. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Sed odio sem, hendrerit in tortor in, cursus aliquam orci. Etiam sed dolor lobortis, fringilla elit nec, tincidunt odio. Maecenas et consectetur ante, quis ullamcorper ex. Quisque tempor mollis mattis. Aliquam tempus tellus eu posuere ullamcorper. Duis tempor libero vel quam accumsan congue.<br><br>

Curabitur porta congue eros eu vulputate. Donec a lacus a ante accumsan faucibus sit amet sit amet enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vivamus interdum dui nisi, sed placerat tortor consectetur at. Aenean volutpat ex non risus sagittis, nec pulvinar justo consequat. Proin eget nibh quis erat suscipit pulvinar. Etiam varius neque id dui volutpat, nec tempor eros venenatis. In ullamcorper dignissim lorem quis imperdiet.<br><br>

Nunc hendrerit maximus dignissim. Pellentesque eget dui erat. Curabitur sed justo accumsan, varius elit eu, fringilla ligula. Fusce varius magna id blandit placerat. Etiam aliquam nunc sed pulvinar tincidunt. Nullam ut sodales tellus. Mauris bibendum pretium dui a lobortis. Suspendisse sit amet consectetur nisl. Aliquam enim sem, tincidunt ut molestie ornare, tristique ut nibh. Nam lacinia scelerisque tortor, eget pretium eros aliquam quis. Mauris volutpat quis tellus eu pharetra. Ut a cursus turpis. Cras placerat ante sit amet leo ultricies convallis.<br><br>

Curabitur sollicitudin iaculis porta. Proin tellus libero, laoreet ut eros vitae, ultricies vestibulum est. Pellentesque iaculis, risus eget eleifend blandit, dui nisl venenatis mauris, at finibus orci turpis sit amet ligula. Nunc sed nisi sit amet diam congue maximus eget at metus. Duis suscipit magna a tortor porta laoreet. Donec ac magna non turpis porta varius eget ac urna. Cras et nibh odio. Nullam vitae sem justo. Morbi laoreet vehicula sem, elementum maximus erat egestas id. Curabitur id eros purus. Nullam eget nibh a augue tristique interdum nec eu nunc. Suspendisse potenti. Ut sed finibus eros. Ut in tortor et neque cursus tempor et sit amet orci.<br><br>
  <div id="footer">
  </div><!-- #footer -->
  
 </div><!-- #wrapper -->
 
</body>
```

In IE 11.0 all ok, but in FF and Chrome there is a small vertical scrollbar. If I change in #footer `bottom:0;` to  `bottom:5px;` all ok. But why? Not critical but I would be very interested how can I avoid it.

Comment: Slightly improved the format + extra tag

Comment: Alexei, doesn't understand you to be honest. Which extra tag?

Comment: @Alexei - extra question tag (`scrollbar`). This comment is related to question reviewing process.

Comment: Ah, understand, thank you.